# How can I dynamically add ckeckboxes to my Rails form?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, ruby-on-rails-4

As you can see I have my main Car form (created with the Form Object) and the form of the Wheel with it's own inputs, images etc. It likes nested in my car form.
When I select checkboxes wheels became added to my car.

How can I dynamically add ckeckboxes to my Car form based on the wheel form?

Associations are such:
*Car has_and_belongs_to_many wheels*

[image]

Comment: What have you tried up to now? Please post some code so that we can guide you based on something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [formstatic](https://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic) gem, where in usage section you can find syntax like

```
  f.input :authors, :as => :check_boxes, :collection => User.order("last_name ASC").all
  f.input :authors, :as => :check_boxes, :collection => current_user.company.users.active
  f.input :authors, :as => :check_boxes, :collection => [@justin, @kate]
  f.input :authors, :as => :check_boxes, :collection => ["Justin", "Kate", "Amelia", "Gus", "Meg"]
```